# Why AppleScript not working since updating Mac?

Tags: macos, applescript

I wrote various scripts sometimes they work sometimes I get (**error "Application isn’t running." number -600 from application "System Events"**) but before updated everything worked fine. Anyone else facing a similar situation or anyone got a solution? I am using macOS Big Sur V 11.2.1 and AppleScript V 2.11 (225)
Heres the Script

```
tell application "System Events"
    delay 5
    set repeatTime1 to random number from 1 to 2
    repeat repeatTime1 times
        delay 0.4
        key code 123
        delay 0.7
        key code 123
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Since **macOS Big Sur** I too have gotten "**Application isn’t running.**" for various _applications_ including **System Events** when running some **AppleScript** _scripts/apps_. Try adding an `activate`, `launch` or `run` _command_.

Comment: Where should I try to add an activate, launch or run command

Comment: As the first _command_ in the `tell` _block_. In this case before the first `delay` _command_. In other words, directly after: `tell application "System Events"`

Comment: thanks mate I tested it out 5 times using your method and it seems to working fine thank you

Comment: The problem still there if I run any script for more than 7 mins

Comment: Update still having the same problem...